# how to read & write xml file in C# not rely on the tag name?

Tags: c#, xml

Thank you very much for reading my question.

the bottom is the sample of my xml file.please refer that.

i did some xml files before, but by "CMarkXml". "IntoElement, OutofElement", is very clear.

but when C#...i was lost..

1: how to read & write my xml file without using the tag name. i see some articles about operation on xml file by c#, but all assumed that known the tag name.

2: if without tag name, it is very difficult or not recommend. then how to read & write my xml file by XmlDocument? (sorry, but no Ling please, i am very faint with that...).

3: my idear is, for the xml file, get out some section, we still could parse the section by xmldocument.

4: for the write/modify the xml file, of course, should contain delete some section, delete some "leaf", change the attributes...

Thank you very much for reading the long question, and any help i will very appreciate. If you have a good sample code but not continent paste them here, could you send it to "erlvde@gmail.com"?

```
<root>
    <a>i belong to a</a>
    <b>
        <bb>
            <bb>1</bb>
            <bb>2</bb>
            <bb>3</bb>
            <bb>4</bb>
            <bb>5</bb>
        </bb>
        <bb>
            <bb>1</bb>
            <bb>2</bb>
            <bb>3</bb>
            <bb>4</bb>
            <bb>5</bb>
        <bb>
    ....(other <bb>)
    </b>
</root>
```

Comment: Better formatting of the xml file would help

Comment: Have a look at [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) is a tutorial for serializing to and from XML which shows you how to manipulate the element names etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer. sigh,,i tried to read XmlSerializer before, but...sorry, maybe, the XmlDocument is the only one i can understand..what the funny is, i can't do it by XmlDocument...

Comment: Do you have control over the XML schema?

Comment: I created a sample based on your updates to the XML schema which will produce what you're looking for and edited my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Read your xml into `XmlDocument`:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("XML HERE");
```

Access child nodes:

```
xmlDocument.ChildNodes[1]
```

But it's also true that it's very error prone

You can also check if you have child nodes at all:

```
xmlDocument.HasChildNodes
```

And get number of child nodes:

```
xmlDocument.ChildNodes.Count
```

Comment: thank you. and you are careful pointing the shortcoming. yes, that assumed we know how many children there is. but unfortunately,, i don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your elements names contain identifiers. If that is the case, and you have control over the XML schema, I would highly recommend changing your XML to contain elements and/or attributes indicating your identifiers and then use the built in [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class for serializing to and from XML. It has many modifiers available, such as [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) and [XmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx) among many others, for formatting the output.

[Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) is a tutorial to get you started.

If possible, change your XML to something like following which would make it far simpler to manipulate...again if changing the schema is a possibility.

```
<root>
    <a>i belong to a</a>
    <b>
        <bb id="1">
            <bb>1</bb>
            <bb>2</bb>
            <bb>3</bb>
            <bb>4</bb>
            <bb>5</bb>
        </bb>
        <bb id="2">
            <bb>1</bb>
            <bb>2</bb>
            <bb>3</bb>
            <bb>4</bb>
            <bb>5</bb>
        <bb>
    </b>
</root>
```

**Edit** *this edit reflects the changes you made to your XML*

---

Here is a simple console application which will serialize an object to an XML file and then rehydrate it.

*Expected XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>i belong to a</a>
  <b>
    <bb>
      <bb>1</bb>
      <bb>2</bb>
      <bb>3</bb>
      <bb>4</bb>
      <bb>5</bb>
    </bb>
    <bb>
      <bb>1</bb>
      <bb>2</bb>
      <bb>3</bb>
      <bb>4</bb>
      <bb>5</bb>
    </bb>
  </b>
</root>
```

*Simple Console Application Demonstration*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new root
            {
                a = "i belong to a",
                b = new List<bb>
                {
                    new bb
                    {
                        bbClassProperty = new List<int>
                        {
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            5
                        }
                    },
                    new bb
                    {
                        bbClassProperty= new List<int>
                        {
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            5
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));

            using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\root.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, items);
                textWriter.Close();
            }

            using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\root.xml"))
            {
                var yourObject = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    #region [Classes]

    public class root
    {
        public string a { get; set; }

        public List<bb> b { get; set; }
    }

    public class bb
    {
        [XmlElement("bb")]
        public List<int> bbClassProperty { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: my elements names don't contain identifiers. could you use XmlDocument instead？ XmlSerializer is difficult to me....

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion...i tried but failed. sorry for the bad format...first time asking question here...

Comment: @erlvde 1. If your element names do not contain identifiers then I suggest that you provide more details on what you are trying to model. 2. Don't be afraid of XmlSerializer as it is dead simple to use. Have a look at the tutorial I posted which will get you there in minutes. 3. No offense, but you could not have tried that hard if you failed seconds after I posted this.

Comment: yeah, thank your very much for your help, i know the name of solution..and i know even not use XmlSerializer, just XmlDocument, can do it. but i am a fresh man when C#, could you give me more information in detail, if smaple code, i will very appreciate. acutlly, i was coding just now, but..still can't do it. i am not meant you solution is bad to my question, the problem is i don't know how to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `ChildNodes` (and similar) properties and methods on your `XmlElement` object. These will let you iterate over the children of a node and you can then ask that node for its name.

Comment: very thank you! the first answer. i read some articles already, but not suits my xml file( is my xml file so special?), and if you know some solution, could you put some sample here? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_properties.aspx) object, you can use XMLNode.FirstChild to get the child, if it has any. You can also use XMLNode.NextSibling to get the next Node of the same parent node.
Why can't you use the names of the nodes? It's the easiest and most common way. Especially if you use XPath or similar.

[XPath](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPATH) is also the answer to your second question.

Comment: sign, becuase the xml file may be changed later. ok, i tried by "tag name". and for the node <a>, i can parse it, but for <b> i failed, because <b> is so complex..

Comment: @erlvde: If there are no rules how the xml file is build then it's hard to parse it. But the documentation shows how many possible ways there are how to parse a file. Is this your own xml file? Is there a xsl file? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? People have shown many ways how to parse a xml-file without knowing the tag or attribute names.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  i know the name of solution..and i know even not use XmlSerializer, just XmlDocument, can do it. but i am a fresh man when C#, could you give me more information in detail, if smaple code, i will very appreciate. acutlly, i was coding just now, but..still can't do it. i am not meant you solution is bad to my question, the problem is i don't know how to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

U can use the class XML reader, a simple example is given [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader).

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Create an XML reader for this file.
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("perls.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        // Only detect start elements.
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            // Get element name and switch on it.
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
            case "perls":
                // Detect this element.
                Console.WriteLine("Start <perls> element.");
                break;
            case "article":
                // Detect this article element.
                Console.WriteLine("Start <article> element.");
                // Search for the attribute name on this current node.
                string attribute = reader["name"];
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("  Has attribute name: " + attribute);
                }
                // Next read will contain text.
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                Console.WriteLine("  Text node: " + reader.Value.Trim());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

The input file text is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<perls>
    <article name="backgroundworker">
    Example text.
    </article>
    <article name="threadpool">
    More text.
    </article>
    <article></article>
    <article>Final text.</article>
</perls>
```

> Output
>
> Start  element.
>
> Start  element.
>
> Has attribute name: backgroundworker
>
> Text node: Example text.
>
> Start  element.
>
> Has attribute name: threadpool
>
> Text node: More text.
>
> Start  element.
>
> Text node:
>
> Start  element.
>
> Text node: Final text.`enter code here`

You can use the following code to if the file does not contain the headers, in the example above.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, settings)
```

Comment: thank you. yours is the best sample in detail. but..seems can't parse my xml file. i used the one before. for the node <bb_number>, it has children, what can i do then?

Comment: it will parse all the child nodes. run the sample code for your file, and put the check if string.IsNullorEmpty(reader.value), if it is empty, it has child nodes or no value in it. Try it once.

Comment: remove the switch statement, just check whether its d start element, call read() den check the value

Comment: thank you very much. but could you make the sample code by my xml file? if not convenient pasting code here, please email to erlvde@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
void Iterate(XmlNode parent) {
    //do something with
    //parent.Name
    //parent.Value
    //parent.Attributes

    foreach(XmlNode child in parent.ChildNodes) {
        Iterate(child);
    }
}

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(filename);

XmlNode parent = document.DocumentElement;
Iterate(parent);
```

You could also store it like that (sorry for any syntactical error, didn't run it)

```
public class Document {
    public Element DocumentElement { set; get; }

    private void Load(string fileName) {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(fileName);

        DocumentElement = new Element(this, null);
        DocumentElement.Load(document.DocumentElement);
    }
}

public class Element {
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
    //other attributes

    private Document document = null;
    private Element parent = null;
    public Element Parent { get { return parent; } }
    public List<Element> Children { set; get; }
    private int order = 0;

    public Element(Document document, Element parent) {
        Name = "";
        Value = "";
        Children = new List<LayoutElement>();

        this.document = document;
        this.parent = parent;
        order = parent != null ? parent.Children.Count + 1 : 1;
    }

    private Element GetSibling(bool left) {
        if(parent == null) return null;
        int add = left ? -1 : +1;
        Element sibling = parent.Children.Find(child => child.order == order + add);
        return sibling;
    }

    public Element GetLeftSibling() {
        return GetSibling(true);
    }

    public Element GetRightSibling() {
        return GetSibling(false);
    }

    public void Load(XmlNode node) {
        Name = node.Name;
        Value = node.Value;
        //other attributes

        foreach(XmlNode nodeChild in node.Children) {
            Element child = new Element(document, this);
            child.Load(nodeChild);
            Children.Add(child);
        }
    }
}

Document document = new Document();
document.Load(fileName);
```

For changing/deleting right now you could iterate the tree and find elements by name, but since name is not unique, you would affect many elements at once. You could add an unique id in every tag like

```
<bb id="bb1"/>
```

Then read it in Load function like

```
id = ((XmlElement)node).GetAttribute("id");
```

and use this id to iterate through the tree. Sorry I don't have time right now to provide something more detailed.

Comment: really thank you..this is the best answer in detail. but how to delete/change? i want to make a function such as deleteTag(string sTagName)...is it a good idear?